# No request handling method with name X in class Y

Tags: java, spring-mvc, netbeans-7

The problem:
A simple link between pages doesn't want to work. I have my .jsp page (I have put a href on the index page to go to it). When I click the link to go the page it says 404 Not found and in GlassFish it's telling me No request handling method with name "AdaugareUtilizator" in class [Controller.MedicController]. So, these are my files:

Dispatcher

```
 <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            <prop key="AdaugareUtilizator.htm">medicController</prop>
            <prop key="TestPage.htm">medicController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="medicController" class="Controller.MedicController"/>
```

And in my Controller class, here is the method:

```
 public ModelAndView AdaugareUtilizator(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) throws Exception 
  {
     ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView("AdaugareUtilizator");
     return mv;       
  }
```

If it matters I'm working in NetBeans 7.3. I assure you that the links and names are all correct, I've checked and double checked them. I know this is a basic thing and I've been staring at this problem for over an hour and don't know what else to do to it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Controller class` check for  `import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;` and tell me how it worked.

Comment: I had a different import which made things crash... Good catch!